# Creating redirect link with calculated parameters

Tags: html, redirect

I am using the following code to redirect visitors on my website:

```
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://mylink.com">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location.href = "http://mylink.com"
    </script>
```

I would like to add dates to the link so that the link becomes this:
"http://mylink.com/**startdate=2016-01-09;enddate=2016-02-09**"

I would also like to set the **startdate** parameter set to tomorrow's date and **enddate** parameter to be calculated based on the **startdate** value.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Although JavaScript is not tagged in your question, I would do something like this:

```
function formatDate(date) {
  var days = date.getDate();
  var months = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var fixedDays = (days < 10)? ("0" + days) : days;
  var fixedMonths = (months < 10)? ("0" + months) : months;
  var result = (1900 + date.getYear()) + "-" 
    + fixedMonths + "-" + fixedDays;
  return result;
}
function createLink(baseUrl, daysExpiration) {
  var tomorrow = new Date();
  tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
  var expire = tomorrow;   
  expire.setDate(expire.getDate() + daysExpiration);
  var result = baseUrl +
    "/startdate=" + formatDate(tomorrow) + 
    ";enddate=" + formatDate(expire);
  return result;
}
var link = createLink("www.ex.com", 30);
window.location = link;
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sLtxbvoj/1/).

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you.